# Методы just в RxJava

Tags: java, android, rxjava

Просматривая исходники библиотеки *io.reactivex.rxjava2*, в  классе `Observable<T>` обнаружила интересную (или странную?) вещь - 10 методов `just`, сигнатура которых выглядит следующим образом:

```
just(T item)
just(T item1, T item2)
just(T item1, T item2, T item3)
just(T item1, T item2, T item3, T item4)
just(T item1, T item2, T item3, T item4, T item5)
just(T item1, T item2, T item3, T item4, T item5, T item6) 
just(T item1, T item2, T item3, T item4, T item5, T item6, T item7)
just(T item1, T item2, T item3, T item4, T item5, T item6, T item7, T item8)
just(T item1, T item2, T item3, T item4, T item5, T item6, T item7, T item8, T item9) 
just(T item1, T item2, T item3, T item4, T item5, T item6, T item7, T item8, T item9, T item10)
```

В чём глубокий смысл этого?.. Почему нельзя было сделать как-нибудь вроде `just(T... item)`? Почему методов именно 10?

Comment: Почему нельзя было сделать как-нибудь вроде just(T... item)?

Не очень понятно как именно сделать. Привидите пример.

Answer (score 4):

Вероятно, это сделано, чтобы эти статические методы можно было приводить к функциональным интерфейсам семейства `rx.functions.Func*`

```
public interface Func1<T, R> extends Function {
    R call(T t);
}

...

public interface Func9<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, R> extends Function {
    R call(T1 t1, T2 t2, T3 t3, T4 t4, T5 t5, T6 t6, T7 t7, T8 t8, T9 t9);
}
```

Comment: Но в целом странное и не особо красивое решение конечно...

Comment: Ну функциональная парадигма в Java в принципе не очень изящно вписывается.